# Don't change the name on the listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a `listView` in Activity A as shown below. All the values and name were actually returned from Activity C to B then only A.

[image]

When the first list is clicked, it should display text `Project` and value `3` on `editText` B. But it displays `Medical` which was actually getting from the last list.

[image]

After I change the value from 3 to 43 and return to A, the name changed. What should I do so that the name will remain the same ?

[image]

**Activity A**

```
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
      ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
      int mClickedPosition;
      adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);
     listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

               listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  // if list clicked
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;


                if (name.equals("Project")) {
                    String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");
                    result = temp[temp.length - 1].trim();
                    result = result.replace("RM","");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Project1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    Log.e("RESULT", "Result= " + result);
                }
                else if(name.equals("Medical"))
                {
                    String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");
                    result = temp[temp.length - 1].trim();
                    result = result.replace("RM","");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Medical.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        return claims;
       }


   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:  // for Project
                result = data.getStringExtra("text"); //get from B
                name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) { // if is icon button clicked
                    m_listItems.add(Text);

                } else {
                    m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;

            case 1:  // for Medical
                result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
                // m_listItems.clear();
                if (mClickedPosition==-1)
                {
                    m_listItems.add(Text);

                }
                else
                {
                    m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
```

**Activity B** (Project1)

```
   if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
            final String Amount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
            final String description1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
            txt1.setText(description1);
            txt.setText(Amount);
        }

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return to A
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        a = "Project";
                        text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                        returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("c", c); // receive from Activity C
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                       finish();
                    }
                });
                       viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // receive from C
                  }
```

**Noted that the `result` in A represents value 3,5 while `name` represents project and Medical**

Comment: try debug and check if you are getting proper name before intent is started

Comment: @Mohit I think it is same with my previous post but this time is name not result

Comment: @Tony, you can simplify your code by making a custom listview, it would be easier and more readable you will have

Comment: yes it is same that is why asking whether your are getting right value when you debug or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following is your custom object which you want to populate in `listview`

```
MyItem.java

public class MyItem {

    private String name;

    private String something;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

layout for individual item how it would appear in `ListView` this is the file name `my_single_item.xml` **below is the content for the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the adapter which will populate the underlying list of `MyItems` inside `listview` by making individual item

```
MyAdapter.java

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 18-11-2015.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyItem> myItems;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MyItem> myItems) {
        super(context, resource, myItems);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.myItems = myItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_single_item, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_first);
        TextView something = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_second);
        MyItem myItem = myItems.get(position);
        name.setText("" + myItem.getName());
        something.setText("" + myItem.getSomething());
        return view;
    }
}
```

write this code in your activity

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
ArrayList<MyItem> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    MyItem myItem = new MyItem();
    myItem.setName("Name_" + i);
    myItem.setSomething("RM_" + i);
    myItems.add(myItem);
}

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myItems);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyItem myItem = (MyItem)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+myItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

make sure you do add a listview in this activities layout

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

you would see the toast will match the item you would click now use this object and pass it to any activity you want and it will have the values you clicked on

Comment: how about if I wanted to add list dynamically?

Comment: @Tony, you can certainly add more items to the list and update the adapter by calling NotifiyDataSetChanged, and the listview to which this adapter is attached will be updated

Comment: I need to pass the value from B to `onActivityResult` A first like what I posted?

Comment: @Tony, just serialize the myItem object send it to second activity and de-serialize  and you will have your data in second activity

Comment: What's the different between `listView`
 and `custom listView`?

Comment: if you only provide a String array to your adapter then you can not play around and make your own individual item in listview, but you can have different widgets and function with customized listview @Tony

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95401/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-tony).

Comment: where you get `simple_list_item_1` ?

Comment: @Tony, `simple_list_item_1` is a layout created in layout directory

Comment: what should have inside the layout?