# Unable to retrieve query using parse

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

Hello I'm learning android and trying to display a customized ListView but it fails to load. The issue comes from my query as the list is empty. Please what did i do wrong as i was following parse example.

Below is my code using fragments to display the view as it fails to get inflated.

**EventTab.java:**

```
        //query Events for current user
        private void queryEventListFromParse(){

            //Create query for objects of type "Event"
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
            // Restrict to cases where the author is the current user.
            //pass in a ParseUser and not String of that user

            query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            query.orderByAscending("createAt");

            // Run the query
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> eventList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // If there are results, update the list of event and notify the adapter
                        Log.d(TAG, "Im in background"); //im able to display image
                        eventList.clear();
                        for (ParseObject event : eventList) {
                            eventList.add(event);
                        }

                        updateEventsList();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Event retrieval error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**
Thanks to Shadow Droid for pointing out the error. The reason why getView() fails to be called due to the List called evenList returning 0. This fails to get getView called and hence returns 0 and fails to display the list.

Below is error message when i commented `eventList.clear();`

Error from console:

```
12-05 04:52:10.511  11450-11450/com.example.davchen.skibuddies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.davchen.skibuddies, PID: 11450
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.EventTab$1.done(EventTab.java:87)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.EventTab$1.done(EventTab.java:80)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: if getting any error or crash then share it

Comment: post listview_event_item.xml and stack trace

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it fails to display the custom list.

Comment: @user3497437: also override `getCount` method then try to run it and use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it doesn't crash but fails to display the custom list

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK tried overriding getCount() and changing from getActivity.getApplicationContext() but no success

Comment: @johnrao07updated with list_event_item.xml and stack trace

Comment: @user3497437, give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764162/dont-change-the-name-on-the-listview/33765170#33765170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening bcoz you are passing empty **eventList** to your adapter. There is confusion in parameter and global variable.
**Global variable** `private List<Event> eventList;` and it is initialized to empty in onCreate.

**while as parameter** in done method **you are clearing the list** which you get after parsing `eventList.clear();`

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> eventList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // If there are results, update the list of event and notify the adapter
                        Log.d(TAG, "Im in background"); //im able to display image
                        eventList.clear();
                        for (ParseObject event : eventList) {
                            eventList.add(event);
                        }

                        updateEventsList();

                    } else {
```

**hence your adapter is getting count as zero and it will not call getView method.** 
**As a solution I would suggest** to check by commenting the  `eventList.clear();` and if works properly and still you require to clear list then go for different variable or parameter name

Comment: yes thanks i noticed that. I commented it out but returned an error?